# org-mode - no refile targets

Tags: org-mode, refile

I am trying to use the refile function but don't understand why I get the error
`no refile targets` after hitting the Cc Cw key.

Here is the content of `org-refile-targets` variable :

`Its value is (("~/gtd/gtd.org" :maxlevel . 3) ("~/gtd/someday.org" :level . 1) ("~/gtd/tickler.org" :maxlevel . 2))`

Original value was nil and defined through this function in .emacs

`(setq org-refile-targets '(("~/gtd/gtd.org" :maxlevel . 3)
                           ("~/gtd/someday.org" :level . 1)
                           ("~/gtd/tickler.org" :maxlevel . 2)))`

All those files exist in the gtd folder. I can capture elements that I are stored into the `~/gtd/inbox.org` file.

I am relatively new to the emacs/org-mode world, the error might be quite stupid.

Comment: Anyone has an idea :)?

Comment: maybe try to replace ~ with full path /home/.../gtd.org

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it didn't change the message ...

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I have no other idea.

Comment: pinecamp suggestion solved it. org-refile-targets creates a list of the defined levels. The list was empty ...

Answer (score 11):

It seems like you're following along with Nicolas Petton's [Orgmode for GTD](https://emacs.cafe/emacs/orgmode/gtd/2017/06/30/orgmode-gtd.html) article; I ran into the same issue this morning.

`org-refile` searches for headings within the files in `org-refile-targets`, up to the level specified. So in your example, `org-refile` will find headings up to level 3 in `~/gtd/gtd.org`, level 2 in `~/gtd/tickler.org`, and only level 1 in `~/gtd/someday.org`. These will then be offered as targets for your refile operation.

To fix this error, simply create some headings in one or more of those files.

Comment: Perfect that fixed it! Didn't understand that it made a list of all possible targets.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I managed to solve after reading this, so I thought I'd add that solution as well in case it helps others.

I'm currently, through no fault of my own, using Windows. Therefore, I had my paths in my `org-refile-targets` set up like this:

```
"C:\Path\to\orgfile.org"
```

I wasn't thinking properly - those backslashes are *interpreted*. So the solution was to switch from backslashes to slashes (which works in Emacs even in Windows):

```
"C:/Path/to/orgfile.org"
```

I'm guessing that double backslashes would also have worked.